# ASP.NET CausesValidation="True" does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with Required field validator controls to validate if the control is empty or not. I put the CausesValidation="True" in the submit button to prevent the form from saving data if there's required field empty and give an appropriate error message.

However, whenever I click submit, nothing happened: NO error message and the form is not saved either.It just stays there without any event occurring.

Also, i noticed even ALL required fields are correctly filled up, it still does nothing upon submitting, unless if I put the CausesValidation="False", then only I am able to submit the form (but no validations take place, which is not what I want).

here's my code:

My Control to validate:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtCostCenter" Text='<%# Bind("CostCenter") %>' MaxLength="254"
                                Size="254" SkinID="InputBox" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvTxtCostCenter" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtCostCenter"
                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:WebResources, ErrorFieldIsRequired %>" />
```

also my Submit button (there  are two submit buttons though, 1 is at the top and the other is at the bottom of the page):

top:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkInsert" runat="server" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:WebResources, ButtonSave %>"
                                CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update">
```

bottom:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:WebResources, ButtonSave %>"
                                CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update">
```

I also tried the ValidationGroup="val" but it still does not work.

Comment: Try adding this key in web.config's `appSettings`: `<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />`. Check if this condition fulfilled too: `UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for XXX`.

Comment: did not work still. what did you mean by check 
UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for XXX

Comment: Have you found errors on browser console? I think you need to check if `UnobtrusiveValidationMode` returning certain error message which mentions `ScriptResourceMapping` there.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but it gives me this

javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new%20WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$DefaultContent$FvEngagementRequest$LinkInsert",%20"",%20true,%20"",%20"",%20false,%20true)):1:1

Comment: Is that error reads `DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined`? Seems this related to handler mapping or browser definition. Which ASP.NET version currently using with?

Comment: if I ran it in IE, the console gave me this :
Unable to set property 'isvalid' of undefined or null reference

also, the target .Net framework is 3.5

Comment: I think you have certain part in JS code which has `isvalid` property but it doesn't being set to hold any value (NB: you're not showing related JS code yet). Try `Page_ClientValidate()` method result to return validation state e.g. `var valid = Page_ClientValidate();`.

Comment: I just figured that if I leave all the fields (both mandatory & not mandatory ones) empty, then submitting the form would give appropriate RequiredField validations to some of the mandatory fields.

however, after filling up all the fields, submitting the form takes me nowhere.

also, if initially i fill up only some of the mandatory fields, submitting the form also does not take me anywhere and error message for the ones I did not fill up also did not appear.

dead end.